# Make Python GUI call specific function

Tags: python, tkinter

So I am having trouble with this code that I have made. What I want it to do is that the user inputs either "real" or "fake" and then they click the submit button and the program outputs this sentence "Your random animal is..." (It will have a random animal in the dots). What I can't get working is the get_animal function. So what this does is it outputs the response to the user. But I can't get it to work with my GUI.

Here is my code:

```
###### IMPORTS ######
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import random

###### FUNCTIONS AND SETUP ######
def get_animal(lit):
    rand_animal = random.choice(lit)
    print("Your random animal is {}".format(rand_animal))


def real_or_fake(user_input):
    user_input.strip()
    if user_input == "Real" or user_input == "Fake":
        return True
    else:
        return False


def main():
    answer = animal.get().capitalize()
    if real_or_fake(answer) == True:
        if answer == "Real":
            response_text.set(get_animal(real_animals))
            play_again = input("Would you like to play again? (Y or N) ").capitalize()
            if play_again == "Y":
                main()
            else:
                exit()

        else:
            response_text.set(get_animal(fake_animals))
            play_again = input("Would you like to play again? (Y or N) ").capitalize()
            if play_again == "Y":
                main()
            else:
                exit()
    else:
        main()

# Set up lists
real_animals = ["horse", "gyrfalcon", "bull", "lion", "meerkat", "cat", "mouse", "moose", "rat", "panda", "stone fish", "anaconda", "python", "owl", "pigeon", "cow", "rabbit", "dog", "narwhal", "killer whale", "shrimp", "plankton", "liger"]
fake_animals = ["unicorn", "phoenix", "minotaur", "orge", "goblin", "hobgoblin", "dragon", "griffin", "centaur", "mermaid", "leviathan", "pegasus", "harpies", "gorgon", "hydra", "sphinx", "raiju", "godzilla", "kraken", "gremlins", "simba", "yogi bear", "bugs bunny", "bambi"]


##### GUI CODE #####
root = Tk()
root.title("Real or Fake")

# Create the top frame
top_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(root, text="Random Animals")
top_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky="NSEW")

# Create and set the message text variable
message_text = StringVar()
message_text.set("Welcome! You can choose either a real animal or a fake animal.")

# Create and pack the message label
message_label = ttk.Label(top_frame, textvariable=message_text, wraplength=500)
message_label.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

# Create the bottom frame
bottom_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(root, text="User Input")
bottom_frame.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=5, sticky="NSEW")

# Create and set the account details variable
animal_details = StringVar()
animal_details.set("Animal: \nWe're going to give you an animal. Would you like Real or Fake? ")

# Create the details label and pack it into the GUI
details_label = ttk.Label(bottom_frame, textvariable=animal_details, justify="center")
details_label.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=10, pady=3)

# Create a variable to store the amount
animal = StringVar()
animal.set("")

# Create an entry to type in amount
animal_entry = ttk.Entry(bottom_frame, textvariable=animal)
animal_entry.grid(row=5, column=1, padx=20, pady=5)

# Create a submit button
submit_button = ttk.Button(bottom_frame, text="Submit", command=main)
submit_button.grid(row=7, column=1, padx=100, pady=5)

#  Create the response variable
response_text = StringVar()

# Create the response label and pack it in the GUI
response_label = ttk.Label(top_frame, textvariable=response_text)
response_label.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=10, pady=10)


#Run the main function
root.mainloop()
```

If you have any suggestions on how to make this works, that would be great thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the value, not print it. Like so:

```
def get_animal(lit):
    rand_animal = random.choice(lit)
    return "Your random animal is {}".format(rand_animal)
```